# Android: capture image intent, photo file size is zero bytes?

Tags: android

I'm following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
to capture photos and save them to the external storage.

Images are captured and saved successfully but the image size file is zero bytes.

The strange thing is that I can still open the file with the stock gallery app, but when copying the image file to the PC, I can't open it with any image viewer.

What can be wrong here? I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found what was wrong. I left the phone for a couple of hours and returned to check the files and surprisingly I found them with their proper files.

Not sure what's the reason for this, I tested the same code on a Samsung S3 and it worked fine, maybe this happens on slow old phones like the Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Did you came across any solution to handle this? Basically different devices are taking different amount of time to write to the file. So a constant wait time across all devices won't be a good option.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is an old question and I didn't find a specific solution to that problem

Comment: After a lot of search i fortunately found the working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717371/picture-file-captured-with-camera-intent-empty-for-a-while-in-onactivityresult

Answer (score 2):

Change the directory to save the captured images and copy the saved image and paste it in another directory in mobile itself.

Comment: Do you mean that the problem in saving the files in the nvironment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES ?